# Filtering a tuple a Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a tuple with four columns/features, and wish to filter the rows based on the value of a column.

`score =[a for a in tup if a[1] == 0.1]`

The output is `print(score)`

```
[array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.00000000e-08,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   2.39502662e-08,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   5.73615251e-08,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.37382380e-07,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   3.29034456e-07,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   7.88046282e-07,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.88739182e-06,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888054e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   4.52035366e-06,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888054e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.08263673e-05,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888053e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   2.59294380e-05,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888050e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   6.21016942e-05,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888043e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.48735211e-04,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888026e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   3.56224789e-04,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41887986e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   8.53167852e-04,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41887896e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   2.04335972e-03,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41887705e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   4.89390092e-03,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41887377e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.17210230e-02,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41887150e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   2.80721620e-02,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888211e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   6.72335754e-02,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41891897e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.61026203e-01,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41895321e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   3.85662042e-01,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41895312e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   9.23670857e-01,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41892873e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   2.21221629e+00,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41889564e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   5.29831691e+00,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888135e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   1.26896100e+01,
     1.00000000e-05]), array([ -2.41888055e-01,   1.00000000e-02,   3.03919538e+01,
```

I would like to combine all this individual arrays back to one tuple while conserving the sequence of the values. Please help me and provide an method for filtering this tuple.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the term `tuple` correctly? What would that list of arrays look like as a single tuple?

Comment: The shape of the array would be (588, 4).

Comment: I still don't get the use of "tuple". Is it my knowledge that's wrong here? You just want a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes, it's a multidimensional array. The array originates from the gridsearchcv function in scikit.

Comment: In which case I think you just to call `np.vstack(my_list)` where `my_list` is what you have shown.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It means a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Numpy and not have to leave to go to another datatype using [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

A few assumptions I'm assuming the number to compare was 0.01 vs 0.1 in the question.

```
import numpy as np
#put your data (tup) as a numpy array here
tup[np.where(tup[:,1]==0.01)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce to combine them back to one

```
score = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [a for a in tup if abs(a[1] - 0.1) < 10e-9])
```